# Who is Morris Ayin?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I frequently hear that certain things should not be done because of Morris Ayin. People of all backgrounds seem to hold by him, yet I have been unable to find any sforim by Rav Morris. Who is he?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: The name is not Morris Ayin but Maurice Ayin. Maybe that might help in your quest to find his seforim.

Answer (score 10):

According to Rav Yehuda Amar rav (Shabbat 64b)  he is "Big Brother" because he is present even bechadre Chadarim.

Answer (score 6):

Note that many things are **forbidden** because of Morris Ayin. Thus, we see that he is regarded as a *min* (kind) of heretic who is attempting to get (other) people to think that good people are doing the wrong thing. This means that we do not want to read what he says about us and avoid him.

Answer (score 6):

No, the *halachic* concern is that although you might *see* nobody eyeing you, remember the possibility of Morris eyeing.

Answer (score 1):

You've been hearing it incorrectly. The name is *Moreh Zayin* - the teacher of armaments. This is a metaphor for all those teachers who tell you not to do things because someone else may misunderstand you. These teachers stand with "virtual weapons" and give you a guilty look, so that you don't do what's forbidden.

Moreh Zayin come in different forms and they aren't necessarily school teachers. A parent who gives you a guilty look is also a Moreh zayin.